# .Net Maui MediaElement Play mp3 Media Controls Missing

Tags: maui, maui-community-toolkit

I am able to play an embeded mp3 file using .net Maui, but when doing so the media controls do not appear, just a thin line.   Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

```
        <media:MediaElement
            ShouldAutoPlay="True"
            ShouldShowPlaybackControls="True"
            Source="embed://Test.mp3" />
```

Comment: Do you have a bit more XAML that you're using for the layout? What happens if you give it a `WidthRequest` and `HeightRequest`? Can you add a screenshot?

Comment: @GeraldVersluis  that worked.  I am new to Maui so I will play around with that a little.  Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 0):

The MediaElement can be missing for two main reasons:

- Either it has not been added to your View content,
- Or it has no configured size.

I have been able to add a MediaElement inside a Grid and it has a defined proportional height.

If you are interested to see it in action, I have written a series of articles about the MediaElement. You can start from [here](https://www.mauicestclair.fr/en/posts/tutos/my-first-app/10-play-music-with-mediaelement).